# Hiro vs other IoC containers

Tags: .net, performance, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

In [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35345/Introducing-Hiro-the-Worlds-Fastest-IOC-Container-.aspx) (11 Apr 2009), the author claims [Hiro](https://github.com/philiplaureano/Hiro) is:

*"the World's Fastest IOC Container... a statically precompiled IOC container that performs as fast as an application without an IOC container"*.

Is it still the fastest IOC container today? Is it ready for production? Are there any other containers can do IOC at compile time? What are its major advantages and disadvantages over other IOC containers?

Thanks

Comment: do you *really* need absolute *top speed* from a **IoC container**, which in 99% of apps is not the bottleneck ever?

Comment: The Simple Service Locator claims to be very fast as well: http://simpleservicelocator.codeplex.com/discussions/236029. I bet it will outperform Hiro.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, Yes, I do :) in my current project, I need to create about 10,000+ objects per 0.1 second. With Ninject, this is impossible (Ninject can only create 2,000 objects per 0.1 second on my machine). I'm currently using Autofac, which is 4 times faster than Ninject. I'm OK with its speed (for my currently project). But my next project might need to handle more objects.

Comment: @caveman: I'd reconsider doing that, I think your app would spend some non-trivial % of time in GC.

Comment: @caveman: Register your services as singleton whenever possible. This saves you from recreating many objects and will often increase performance.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer, @Steven: thanks for your advices. @Steven: I just did a simple test, SimpleServiceLocator is 36 times faster than Autofac. But I think it might be several times slower than Hiro (based on this [benchmarks](http://hiro.googlecode.com/files/Performance.zi_)).

Comment: @caveman: I believe your benchmarks are not realistic. Hiro has one nasty problem that you have overlooked. Its performance degrades linearly with the number of types you register. Register for instance 20 mappings *before* (this is important: **before**) the IWebApp mapping and you will see the performance is equal to that of the SSL (note that I used the last check-in, which is about twice as fast as v0.14). The performance characteristics of Hiro are O(n) while SSL keeps constant: O(1). In a normal sized application it is very common to have many mappings.

Comment: @caveman the component you're creating 10,000 times per second - if it is such a hot path, why not just fall back to using "new"? Usually optimisation means using the cleanest tools/techniques/patterns for 99% of the code, then whatever's quickest for that hot 1%...

Comment: @caveman: Hiro now does its lookups in O(1) time, thanks to the OpCodes.Switch instruction. Try running the latest version of Hiro, and let me know if its faster: https://github.com/philiplaureano/Hiro

Comment: @plaureano: Thanks for letting me know. I just did a simple test on the latest version (I haven't tested previous versions). Please keep in mind, I'm not professional, so I think my test results are not reliable. I found if I only register one type, Hiro is about 50~60% faster than SimpleServiceLocator. But when I register more types, Hiro gets slower, while SSL stays constant. When I register 70 types, Hiro gets about 25% slower than SSL. But comparing to Steven's test results of the previous version, if I understand correctly, it seems Hiro's performance is greatly increased. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hiro claims to be the fastest container. This statement is based on the benchmark given by the author (see [here](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) for an objective comparison between many containers). Whether or not this benchmark is realistic depends upon the size of your application. The benchmark seems to be cleverly setup with a very small set of registered types. When adding more registrations to the benchmark, the performance starts dropping (see below for an example benchmark of this). When looking closely we can see that Hiro has a performance characteristic of [O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), while normal DI frameworks have a characteristic of O(1), thus with other frameworks the performance stays constant with the number of registered types.

What’s nice about Hiro is that it generates a new assembly on the fly and resolving a new type consists of just a single interface call. This is very fast. Most common DI frameworks on the other hand, will always have to do a dictionary lookup during a call to GetInstance. Hiro’s GetInstance method is basically a big switch case statement internally, implemented as a bunch of if-statements. If-based switch case statements are extremely fast up until a point. The C# compiler uses an heuristic of (I believe) 18 case statements as turning point. Below that number the compiler generates a bunch of if-statements. Above that number it creates and stores a static dictionary and does a dictionary lookup, because above 18 lookups performance of a dictionary lookup if simply faster.

Well guess what; Hiro doesn’t use the optimization as the C# compiler does. That's why the performance keeps dropping as more and more types are added to the container. A linear performance characteristic –or O(n) for short- is okay for small sets of data, but any well written and commonly sized, dependency-friendly application has many type registrations / mappings. And in that case the performance of Hiro drops quickly.

So, to answer your questions:

> Is it still the fastest IOC container
>   today?

For very small applications it is the fastest. For any normal sized applications it has never been the fastest.

> Is it ready for production?

<strike>Hard to say. Its current status is alpha and it misses a lot of features that other IOC framework have.</strike> The developer just (see comments below) published a stable release. This means that according to the developer it is ready for production.

> What are its major advantages 
>   and disadvantages over other IOC containers?

Take a look for instance at [this article](http://blog.ashmind.com/2008/08/19/comparing-net-di-ioc-frameworks-part-1/) (and the [follow up](http://blog.ashmind.com/2008/09/08/comparing-net-di-ioc-frameworks-part-2/)) which gives a good (feature) comparison of IOC frameworks. The writer of the article has a vision of what he thinks is important. You have to make such a list for yourself. Performance seems to be high on your list. However, please note that there are other ways to improve performance. For instance by registering types as singletons to prevent the creation of many types.

Here is a little comparison with other containers. Note that I didn't write Hiro, so I could be missing things, especially since there seems to be no documentation at all, but here goes:

1. You need 4 assemblies to run, instead of 1 or 2 for most IOC frameworks.
2. It throws a stack overflow when a recursive dependency is resolved (most frameworks do this btw). So there is no cyclic dependency detection.
3. <strike>Doesn't seem to support any lifestyle other than transient (the writer does say it [will](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35511/Introducing-Hiro-the-Worlds-Fastest-IOC-Container-.aspx), but I currently see no support for this). This actually is bad for performance, because most services would normally be registered as singletons.</strike> According to the author, it supports multiple lifestyles.
4. Doesn't support resolving open generic types.
5. Doesn't support unregistered type resolution.
6. I has no documentation accept XML (intellisense) documentation.

> Are there any other containers can do
>   IOC at compile time?

Define 'compile time'. Hiro generates a new assembly on the fly once during runtime. Others (like [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), [Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) and [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com)) emit IL or compile delegates under the covers. This isn't any slower than compiling the complete assembly in one go (however, there is the overhead of calling the delegate which is a tiny bit slower than making an interface call).

BTW, I changed the benchmark to see the behavior described above appear. With 50 extra types registered you will see that Hiro performs already **three times as slow** as with the initial benchmark.  Here is the code I used:

```
public interface IHandler<T> { }

public class Handler<T> : IHandler<T> { }

public class HiroUseCase : UseCase
{
    IMicroContainer container;

    private static void RegisterHandler<T>(DependencyMap map)
    {
        map.AddService(typeof(IHandler<T>), typeof(Handler<T>));
    }       

    public HiroUseCase()
    {
        var map = new DependencyMap();

        // *** My added registrations
        RegisterHandler<byte>(map);
        RegisterHandler<byte?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<short>(map);
        RegisterHandler<short?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<ushort>(map);
        RegisterHandler<ushort?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<int>(map);
        RegisterHandler<int?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<uint>(map);
        RegisterHandler<uint?>(map);

        RegisterHandler<long>(map);
        RegisterHandler<long?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<ulong>(map);
        RegisterHandler<ulong?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<float>(map);
        RegisterHandler<float?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<double>(map);
        RegisterHandler<double?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<decimal>(map);
        RegisterHandler<decimal?>(map);

        RegisterHandler<DateTime>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DateTime?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<char>(map);
        RegisterHandler<char?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<object>(map);
        RegisterHandler<string>(map);
        RegisterHandler<bool>(map);
        RegisterHandler<bool?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<Enum>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DateTimeKind>(map);

        RegisterHandler<DateTimeKind?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DateTimeOffset>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DateTimeOffset?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DayOfWeek>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DayOfWeek?>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DBNull>(map);
        RegisterHandler<Delegate>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DivideByZeroException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<DllNotFoundException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<Exception>(map);

        RegisterHandler<KeyNotFoundException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<InvalidOperationException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<InvalidCastException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<InvalidProgramException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<InvalidTimeZoneException>(map);
        RegisterHandler<IDisposable>(map);
        RegisterHandler<IComparable>(map);
        RegisterHandler<IEquatable<int>>(map);
        RegisterHandler<IEnumerable>(map);
        RegisterHandler<IEqualityComparer>(map);

        // *** Original benchmark setup
        map.AddService(typeof(IWebApp), typeof(WebApp));
        map.AddService(typeof(IAuthenticator), typeof(Authenticator));
        map.AddService(typeof(IStockQuote), typeof(StockQuote));
        map.AddService(typeof(IDatabase), typeof(Database));
        map.AddService(typeof(IErrorHandler), typeof(ErrorHandler));
        map.AddService(typeof(ILogger), typeof(Logger));

        IContainerCompiler compiler = new ContainerCompiler();
        var assembly = compiler.Compile(map);;

        var loadedAssembly = assembly.ToAssembly();
        var containerType = loadedAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
        container = (IMicroContainer)Activator
            .CreateInstance(containerType);
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        var webApp = 
            (IWebApp)container.GetInstance(typeof(IWebApp), null);
        webApp.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Steven, very interesting analysis ... I would have assumed that Hiro's code gen would be more like new A(new B(new C()), new D())... Seems like a missed opportunity. Then again, many containers e.g. Windsor do emit IL that's practically equivalent.

Comment: @Nicholas: Thanks. Hiro still does `new A(new B(new C()), new D())` under the covers (as we all tend to do nowadays), but the difference is that for finding the correct type, Hiro does something like this: `if (type == TypeA) { ... } else if (type == TypeB) { ... } else if (type == TypeC) { ... } else if ...`. Performance is great with TypeA, but would be very poor for TypeZZ.  Performance would have been be much better when Hiro generated a balanced search tree, which would be O(log n).

Comment: Good analysis, but you missed a few points there, Steven: 1) Hiro uses ILMerge so that the release version is only one assembly, 2) There *is* cyclic DI if you make the dependencies lazy and have it resolved at runtime, 3) Hiro does support other lifestyles (including Singleton, Transient, and Once-per-web session), and 4&5) Yeah, you got me there -- I intentionally left Open Generics out of Hiro since that's in LinFu, and 6) It's got quite a few XML docs and the use is pretty simple. WYSIWYG :)

Comment: BTW, did you test those same additional registrations on the other containers? If OP is looking for speed, then you might have proven that Hiro is slower than it claims to be, but it doesn't prove that it's slower than the other containers. What does the perf look like across the board?

Comment: @plaureano: The features you are talking about (1 assembly, cyclic dependency validation, and other life styles), are they available in the current release or are you still working on them?

Comment: @plaureano: But as I responded to @Nicholas, If you want to outperform them all, you need to generate a balanced search tree (note that this will be pretty tricky to do, because you'll need to store compare the hash codes and they can collide). In that case it takes around 1024 registrations before you'll get slower than the Simple Service Locator (SSL). Only really big applications get to that point. And when you get at that point, you could in that case still switch to a dictionary, which would make always at least as fast as the SSL.

Comment: @Steve: Here, have an upvote. It looks like I have some work to do. :)

Comment: FIXED: I modified Hiro to use the OpCodes.Switch instruction for resolving services in O(1) time: http://is.gd/62qV7T --again, Steve, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Steve: Oh, and the other lifestyles have been available for over a year now. Hiro has been stable for production for over a year now, and I don't plan on adding any more features. Less is more.

Comment: @Plaureano: Please post a link to the download of the production assembly, so I can check it out.

Comment: @Plaureano: I like to test the newest version, but I can't get my code to compile with the production release. C# gives me the following error: `'Hiro.Interfaces.IContainerCompiler.Compile(string, string, string, Hiro.Interfaces.IDependencyContainer)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.` I referenced all 5 assemblies that are included in the release.

Comment: @Steven: Could you send me the test code so I can take a look at it? my email is marttub(atsign)hotmail(dot)com. Thanks

Comment: There was an error in the build script in the last commit, but it should be fixed now: https://github.com/philiplaureano/Hiro/commit/6193eb98922375a94cdd5422b9ec0da03c2a6176

Comment: @plaureano: I'm trying my best to get and objective view on your library and change my answer according to this, but this is starting to get a bit embarrassing. Even with the 1.01 release, it just doesn’t compile. I’m still getting the same error message as before. You are publishing ‘production ready` software that simply does not compile. Do you actually test your software?

Comment: @Steve: Here you go: http://goo.gl/2Nf8i - This latest benchmark includes most IOC containers (including Hiro). Disclaimer: I didn't write this benchmark (or the other one for that matter), so feel free to test it however you wish. That's about as objective as it gets.

Comment: @Steve: And for the record, I do test my software but I can't help you if you're trying to use a benchmark against an alpha version of Hiro when the production version is entirely different. The IContainerCompiler class is public in the production version, so clearly there's a versioning problem, not a testing problem.